# Makefile for using make as gcc

Tags: gcc, makefile

Is it possible to write universal Makefile which would get any target and act like a wrapper to gcc, but with parameters? For example, this means that

```
make 01.c
```

will have the same result as

```
g++ -o 01.out 01.c
```

Answer (score 0):

`make` already has several ["implicit rules"](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules) to do what you're trying.

For example, even with *no makefile*,

```
make 01.o
```

Will run:

```
c++ -c -o 01.o 01.cpp
```

If it finds a file called `01.cpp` in your current directory.  You can set the `CXXFLAGS` environment variable if you want to pass more flags.  If you're really set on using `g++` rather than the system compiler, you can set `CXX=g++`, too.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - You using implicit rules.

Summat like (if memory serves me right)

```
.cpp.o:
    $(CCC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Maybe in the set of default implicit rules

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wildcard - `%`.

However, the thing specified on the commandline is the target, not the source - what you want, not what you have.

It looks like what you want is approximately:

```
%.out: %.c
    g++ -o $@ $<
```

This means: to make (something).out, first make sure you have (something).c, then run g++ -o (something).out (something).c

$@ is always the target file, and $< is the first prerequisite.

You will need to run `make 01.out`, not `make 01.c`